# change text of TLFTextField through constructor

Tags: actionscript-3, tlf

I have a symbol which extends `MovieClip` and it has a `TLFTextField` instance in it. I try to change the text of the `TLFTextField` in the constructor, like this:

```
public function mySymbol() 
{
    myTLF.text = "texty text";
}
```

I create a new instance of the class mySymbol in my DocumentClass:

```
public function DocumentClass() 
{
    var mySymbol:MySymbol = new MySymbol();
    addChild(mySymbol);
}
```

The symbol is created and added to stage (I know that because it has a border and background color) but nothing shows up inside `myTLF`.

If instead of trying to change the text in the constructor, I change it in the `DocumentClass()` (using `mySymbol.myTLF.text = "texty text";` it does show up.

What am I missing here?

Comment: bah. found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656065/tlftextfield-text-property-not-accessible-in-constructor) a minute after posting...

Answer (score 0):

Just so that this question doesn't stay open, I followed the recipe in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656065/tlftextfield-text-property-not-accessible-in-constructor): I added an event listener for `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` on the symbol holding the `TLFTextField`, and in the event handler I could change the text.